# Swift 5 : Wait on Global Queue to finish execution on on main queue

Tags: ios, swift5

We got a project from another team as the original dev left the org. I need to fix a defect. I have some code like below where `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` happens on `Global` queue. But this gives memory warnings as below `UIView` extension's `renderToImage` does not happens on `main` thread.

I wanted to wrap the `renderToImage` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` but it would break the `for` loop in `someFunction`. I can't use `.sync` on main thread. Can someone tell me how can I finish `renderToImage` waiting on `Global` queue?

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
             let pdfData = NSMutableData()
             UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

             zip(self.pdfPages, self.pageViews).forEach { (page, view) in

                 let image = view.renderToImage()
                 guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5),
                     let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

                 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: page.originSize), nil)
                 compressedImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: page.originSize))

                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.progressLabel.text = "Processing PDF... \(page.pageNumber) / \(pageNumbers)"
                 }
             }
             UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating()
                 self.progressView.isHidden = true
                 completionBlock?(pdfData as Data)
             }
         }


extension UIView {
    func renderToImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return UIImage() }
        layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
}
```

After applying @paulw11 answer:

```
    fileprivate func generatePDF(_ completionBlock: ((_ pdfData: Data) -> Void)?) {

        let pageNumbers = pageViews.count

        progressView.isHidden = false
        progressIndicator.startAnimating()
        progressLabel.text = "Processing PDF... \(0) / \(pageNumbers)"

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let pdfContextQueue = DispatchQueue(label: kMessagesFaxPDFConversionQueue, target: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

        pdfContextQueue.async {
            zip(self.pdfPages, self.pageViews).forEach { (page, view) in
                view.renderToImage { image in
                    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5),
                    let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

                    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: page.originSize), nil)
                    compressedImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: page.originSize))

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.progressLabel.text = "Processing PDF... \(page.pageNumber) / \(pageNumbers)"
                    }
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
                semaphore.wait()
            }
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.progressView.isHidden = true
                completionBlock?(pdfData as Data)
            }
        }
}


extension UIView {
    func renderToImage(completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)

             guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                 completion(UIImage()); return
             }

             self.layer.render(in: context)
             let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
             UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

             completion(image!)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `NSMutableData` with swift. Just use `Data`.

Comment: @Paulw11: UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData expect NSMutableData

Comment: @paulw11: Is it even right to have `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` on main queue and having `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext` on Global Queue? Is that why I am not having pdfData?

Comment: They are different contexts. One is a context that has been created to render the image, the other is the context into which you are rendering the PDF.  What exactly do you mean when you the PDF isn't being generated?  Is the length of the data 0? Is it non-zero but blank content?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is if you can't simply perform the work on the main queue - Does it really take that long that there is a noticeable impact on the UI?  What else would the user be doing while the PDF was being generated anyway?  If they are waiting for the PDF to be generated so that it can be shared or printed, then simply showing a spinner may be enough.

If you do want to keep the work on another queue then I would convert `renderToImage` to an asynchronous function and use a `DispatchSemaphore` to block your work queue until the loop iteration is complete.

```
func someFunction() {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:0)
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"PDFQueue", target: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
    queue.async {
        for view in PDFViews {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
            zip(self.pdfPages, self.pageViews).forEach { (page, view) in
                view.renderToImage { image in 
                   if let image = image {
                      ...
                      ...
                   }
                   semaphore.signal()
                }
                semaphore.wait()
            }
        }
    }   
}

extension UIView {
    func renderToImage(completion: ((UIImage?)->Void)) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0.0)
            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                completion(nil)
            }

            layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            completion(image)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would recommend create another queue to handle the task then complete renderImage on main queue rather than block global queue, a serial queue with `target` is global queue might work well.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init

Comment: @Paulw11 : Hi, this helped a lot. Very much appreciate it. But, I see returned images are in serial order. But PDF is not getting generated.  I have updated the code in original question. Do you mind checking once please? In my original code the `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` and `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext` are happening on different threads. But still it is fine. Do you mind checking please?

Comment: Have you set some breakpoints to see what is going on. There are lots of places where you could get `nil`

Comment: @paulw11: Actually I did not get nil at all. The serial order is really great. I never used semaphore. Thanks to you. But the PDF is not getting generated.